# Melting pandas DataFrame and using values as Columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I was playing with pandas in order to get used to it, and I ask myself if it's possible to do in pandas without much hassle using melt functionality?

I am using quite famous [titanic.csv](https://github.com/danielc92/python_nb_sklearn_logistic_regression/blob/master/data/titanic.csv) data set.

```py
titanic = pd.read_csv('data/titanic.csv', keep_default_na=True)
titanic.drop(['embarked', 'who', 'adult_male', 'alone', 'parch', 'deck'], \
               axis=1, errors="ignore", inplace=True)
titanic_c = titanic.groupby(['class', 'embark_town', 'gender'])['age'] \ 
                   .mean().reset_index()
titanic_c
```

[image: titanic_c at the momet]

**So here is a question?**

Am I able to use pd.melt to add `embark_town` values as columns that  can looks like this? If yes how?

[image]

Comment: can you add the data as text so we can copy please? thanks

Comment: I put a link to dataset (word titanic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you should use [**`df.pivot_table()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) here and not `melt()`:

```
m=titanic.pivot_table(index=['pclass','sex'],columns='embark_town',values='age')
print(m)
```

---

```
embark_town    Cherbourg  Queenstown  Southampton
pclass sex                                       
1      female  36.052632   33.000000    32.704545
       male    40.111111   44.000000    41.897188
2      female  19.142857   30.000000    29.719697
       male    25.937500   57.000000    30.875889
3      female  14.062500   22.850000    23.223684
       male    25.016800   28.142857    26.574766
```

In your case, you should change `pclass` to `class` and `sex` to `gender`

Comment: it's even creating multiindex!

Comment: @Butuzov yes it does since we have passed 2 indexes in the pivot table, you can call `.reset_index()` if you dont want them. :) : `titanic.pivot_table(index=['pclass','sex'],columns='embark_town',values='age').reset_index().rename_axis(None,axis=1)`